# my cooldown event dosent work as intented discord.js

Tags: error-handling, discord.js

This is my code: https://sourceb.in/PZuJymG20t and it gives me this error:

```
(node:25) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'command' before initialization
    at module.exports (/home/container/events/message.js:32:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:25) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:25) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This is for a cooldown event.

Comment: Please post your code directly to question, no need of adding extra URLs that can become invalid in future.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if(!cooldowns.has(command.name)){
>     cooldowns.set(comman.name, new Discord.Collection());
> }
> const current_time = Data.now()
> const time_stamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
> const cooldown_amount = (command.cooldown) * 1000;
>
> if(time_stamps.has(message.author.id)){
>     const expiration_time = time_stamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldown_amount;
>     if(current_time < expiration_time) {
>         const time_left = (expiration_time - current_time) / 1000;
>
>         return message.reply(`Please wait ${time_left.toFixed(1)} more seconds using this ${command.name}`);
>     }
> }
>
> time_stamps.set(message.author.id, current_time);
> setTimeout(() => time_stamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldown_amount);
> ```

put these chunk of code inside the if(command){} function.

**Why do you get the error?**

You have initiated "command" on line 62, and used it on 32. The way Javascript reads the code is from top to bottom. So basically you have called the command before initialization.

Hope you understand

Comment: explaining your answer would be helpful, thank you